# sign "+" before positive values on axis

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to format data on value axes google chart:

=> sign "+" before positives values
=> sign "-" before negatives values

ex: -2 -1 0 +1 +2 ...

Maybe with options format? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vAxis.format option.  The format option takes an ICU number pattern, which separates out positive and negative formats with a semicolon, so you could have, as an example:

```
vAxis: {
    format: '+#;-#'
}
```

which would format 3 as "+3" and -7 as "-7".